# I am working with Java and Springboot. Is it possible to retrieve only nested json field from a Json document in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("dde3431134247d401b1cef"),
    "_resourceId" : "fwf4-fefre4-ffdfwsc",
    "organizationId" : 343203,
    "domains" : [
        {
            "_resourceId" : "da7-cwcwe-2432d",
            "name" : "d12.net",
            "tenantId" : "A1650",
            "application" : "TEST",
            "activeInd" : true,
            "subdomains" : [
                {
                    "_resourceId" : "fw243-weded3-2eddas",
                    "name" : "name1",
                    "clientName" : "Andrew",
                    "phoneNumber" : "8573458456",
                    "email" : "modalwindow@gmail.com",
                },
                {
                    "_resourceId" : "bce3-cwdd32ede-23ede",
                    "name" : "name2",
                    "clientName" : "client2",
                    "phoneNumber" : "9999999999",
                    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### I am using Springboot and MongoTemplate for the find Query. If I want to retrieve a subdomain based on "domains.subdomain.name" field, can I get only the subdomain json from a mongo query, or do I get the entire document and then iterate and filter the subdomain in my java code.

Answer (score 1):

Use $unwind and then $replaceWith

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "domains.subdomains.name": "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$domains"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$domains.subdomains"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "domains.subdomains.name": "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$domains.subdomains"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OSv0N21T3Ew)

Comment: Is this a good approach to do in mongo, Is it efficient with or without index on 'domains.subdomains.name'

Comment: @Kranthi Yes. You can try it and add `.explain()` before `aggregate()` to see whether index being used or not.